# Fold function in vim

Tags: vim, folding

Is there any way or tools to fold function in vim, like Visual Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: If you mean "folding classes and functions automatically" then you should clarify it explicitly in your question.

Comment: not automatically, users can choose which part he want to fold

Comment: vim has pretty good documentation.  Try :help fold

Comment: Also see :help fold-method

Comment: Depending on the language, there exist plugins that give better results that what vim natively proposes with `&fold` == `syntax` or `indent`.

Comment: Note that there are several languages that have syntax files for vim, but no support for `:set foldmethod=syntax` (yet)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

```
Vim folding commands
---------------------------------
zf#j creates a fold from the cursor down # lines.
zf/ string creates a fold from the cursor to string .
zj moves the cursor to the next fold.
zk moves the cursor to the previous fold.
za toggle a fold at the cursor.
zo opens a fold at the cursor.
zO opens all folds at the cursor.
zc closes a fold under cursor. 
zm increases the foldlevel by one.
zM closes all open folds.
zr decreases the foldlevel by one.
zR decreases the foldlevel to zero -- all folds will be open.
zd deletes the fold at the cursor.
zE deletes all folds.
[z move to start of open fold.
]z move to end of open fold.
```

Source: [Vim docs](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/fold.html#fold-commands).

Comment: zc closes fold under cursor. (warning: figured it by experimenting)

Comment: za will toggle a fold (open if currently closed, and vice versa). I find that pretty handy; almost never use zc or zo.  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding#Opening_and_closing_folds

Comment: `zfgg` folds all lines from top to cursor. 
`zfG` folds all lines from cursor to bottom.

Comment: You can also select multiple lines in Visual Line Mode (`Shift+v`) and fold them with `zf`.

Comment: I used zf% to fold a C function effectively (I don't have a syntax plugin that knows how to do it automatically)

Comment: Actually, as with so many other commands, "zf" ends with a "cursor movement". 
Example: zfH folds from the cursor line to the top of the screen.  
Thus, parking the cursor in an opening "{" and typing "zf%" folds through the end of the block ("%" in an opening cracket or tab jumps to the closing one).

Answer (score 84):

Yes. VIM has exceptional folding capabilities. I don't like learning too many controls, I prefer automation, so here is what I personally use:

In my .vimrc:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=1
set foldclose=all
```

This automatically folds files that you open, based on indent, for everything indented for more than 1 level. The foldclose option makes the fold automatically re-close after I navigate out of the fold.

In-file Controls:

```
zo - opens folds
zc - closes fold
zm - increases auto fold depth
zr - reduces auto fold depth
```

And if you ever get annoyed with the folds, use

```
: set foldmethod=syntax
```

or press:

```
zR
```

to make them all go away.

Comment: I find useful to have:  
`set nofoldenable`  
`set foldlevel=99`  

too. It disables auto folding on opening file and folds only outer functions (not stepping in and folding "fors" and "ifs" and what not)
Made my config based on your answer though, thanks.

Comment: @merinoff Although it will likely never matter, a setting of `foldlevel` greater than 20 has no effect due to that being the internal cap, according to the documentation (for version 8.1).

Comment: After trying out a lot of plugins for a lot of file types, this is the best I found. Clean, easy, no plugins. Thank a lot.

Comment: You do not know the level of excitement I felt when I saw this solution.

Answer (score 27):

```
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

should fold all functions and other blocks automatically, if you have syntax file for your language.

Comment: And `:set foldlevel=999` so that everything is unfolded by default

Answer (score 6):

Vim has excellent folding support.  There is good documentation in the vim help system.  Just open vim and do

```
:help usr_28.txt
```

After reading that you can also read

```
:help folding
```

for some more information.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is bound to the 'z' key, e.g. zO opens all folds. see ":help fold" in vim for more information. You can do folding according to very simple rules, like indentation, or according to the code syntax.