# How can I hide function definitions in Vim?

Tags: function, vim

Not seeing function definitions all over the place would make my code much more readable.

Is there a way to hide them in vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for folding.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding

[Fold function in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362914/fold-function-in-vim)

It allows you to "fold" lines of text into a single line and unfold them later.

Comment: I was hoping for an automatic solution, as manually folding and unfolding can be tedious after a while.

Comment: The linked SO question has some good suggestions. In particular, `:set foldmethod=syntax` or `:set foldmethod=indent` with `foldlevel` will automate this.